# Getting JSON exception while uploading

Tags: android, json, web-services

This is program but getting JSON exception.

```
private void uploadImage(){

    String uploadUrl = "http://...........";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uploadUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mImage.setImageResource(0);
                mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mName.setText("");
                mName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("photo_one",imageString(bitmap));
            params.put("mobile",mName.getText().toString().trim());

            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);

}
```

This is the error I am getting.

> org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of  at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449) at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97) at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:156) at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173) at
>   com.example.athis.practiceproject4.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:93)

Which is `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response)`; line.
What is wrong?

Comment: check your response .

Comment: is your response valid ? and is it json object/array ?

Comment: what is the value of response string

Answer (score 2):

> org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of at

You are getting an empty response.

Answer (score 1):

check you response as error **org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of at** indicates that your response string is null or 0, kindly check for your response string first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code;

```
  HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("photo_one",imageString(bitmap));
  params.put("mobile",mName.getText().toString().trim());

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data....");
    progressDialog.show();

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(uploadUrl, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    String success = (String) response.opt("success");
                    if (success.equals("1") )
                    {

                        // Do your Task here....

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Username & Password...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(req);
```

Comment: What should i write in // Do your Task here... ? I just want to upload one image and text, which i think params.put is already done.

Comment: Simply put Toast there for successfully image uploaded

Comment: Getting D/Volley: [46298] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] Whats wrong?